# JavaFX button not responding on first click

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

```
public void handle(){
    submit.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            LoginConnection login = new LoginConnection(); 
            boolean pass = login.login(usernameField.getText(), passwordField.getText());

            if(pass)
                flip(SceneNames.Main);
            else
                invalLoginMessage.setOpacity(1.00);


        }
    });
    register.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
              flip(SceneNames.Register);                    
        }
    });
}
```

When i click on submit or register, it takes two click for it to do anything. How do i fix this?

Comment: I believe we need more code to answer :)

Comment: Have you tried setting break points inside the two handle methods to check if they are reached on the first click?

Comment: I have not set up break points i will try that.

Comment: Are you using FXML and this method belongs to the controller class?

Comment: I am with @fabian: my guess is that you set the "onAction" attribute in FXML for the buttons to "#handle()", which will just register the event handlers on the first click.

Comment: can you please add modified code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens is that on first click it adds the handlers specified in the method and on second and consecutive clicks, it uses the handlers. To fix it just create separate methods to add through fxml or scene builder.

Comment: could you please elaborate more? I am also facing same issue.